# Creating clickable link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink

I'm new to rails and ruby, and having some growing pains as I learn the basics. I'm currently trying to make an email clickable where the link goes to the user's info page. I've been able to get the email clickable, but it doesn't go anywhere. This is what I have so far

```
column :User do |tweet|
    link_to tweet.user.email, admin_user_path:id
```

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it:

```
link_to tweet.user.email, admin_user_path(@some_admin_obj)
```

Comment: well I need the id in there somewhere, where should I put it?

Comment: Rails can infer the id if you pass in an object, you don't need to specify it.

Comment: I don't know how to pass in an object? Sorry, I have a very basic understanding of ruby and rails. I've gotten the email to be underlined and highlighted like a link should be, but when I click on it I get an error.